# Code Block breaks the pdf using PdfMake

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf-generation, pdfmake

**Scenario :**

- using pdfMake in AngularJS to create a pdf
- and it is working fine except for this code block, which when
  included inside the div marked for the pdf creation results in a
  blank pdf.

This is the block in question:

```
<div ng-repeat="thumb in responseArray" ng-if="responseArray.length >= 1">
        <p>_____________________________________</p>
        <p>Supplier ID: {{thumb.supplier_id}}</p>  
        <p>Supplier Name: {{thumb.supplier_name}}</p> 
        <p>Staked: {{thumb.staked}}</p>
        <p>Returns: {{thumb.returns}}</p>
        <p>Gross: {{thumb.gross}}</p>
        <p>Details: {{thumb.chargeDetailsSummary}}</p>        
        <p>Total Charge: {{thumb.charge}}</p>   
    </div>
```

My code for generating the pdf is as follows:

```
 s.export = function(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportThis'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
            }
        });
    }
```

Anyone knowledgeable on pdfMake have any suggestions as to why and how to fix please?

Open to all suggestions, Please suggest.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="thumb in responseArray">
                 Supplier Id: {{thumb.supplier_id}}
                 Supplier Name:{{thumb.supplier_name}}
                 Staked: {{thumb.staked}}
                 Returns: {{thumb.returns}}
                 Gross: {{thumb.gross}}
                 Details: {{thumb.chargeDetailsSummary}}
                 Total Charge: {{thumb.charge}}
            </p>
```

Guess it was just an issue with the div tag.